# ActiveRecord Query for Detail and Summary Data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using Rails3, I have a `downloads` table with `download_date` and `credits` columns. What I want to generate is a table like:

```
 Date        Credits
 2010-11-01  25
 2010-11-01  27
*2010-11-01  52  <= Sum of previous 2 rows
 2010-11-02  32
*2010-11-02  32  <= Sum of previous row
```

This can be accomplished using something like:

```
u.downloads.group_by(&:download_date).each do |date, downloads|
  downloads.each do |d|
    puts " %10s  %3d" % [d.download_date, d.credits]
  end
  puts "*%10s  %3d" % [date, downloads.sum(&:credits)]
end
```

This solution, while it works, is not too Rails-like and results in a fairly large number of SQL queries being issued. Assuming 100 users x 10,000 downloads / year and the query count  by the end of a year is on the order of 1,000,000 for every one of these pages served.

Any solution I come up with should be database-agnostic if at all possible. I know I'll be using PostgreSQL on Heroku for deployment, and my development version, however misguided, is still running on MySQL.

I hope I've provided sufficient information about the problem domain and the issues involved. Any opinions or suggestions?

Comment: I should add that optimizing is good (thanks Fabio!) but the two things I am looking for specifically is very Rails'ey way to do this that doesn't rely on Array#group_by, as that iterates the in-memory batch of AR objects simply for grouping, and then I have to revisit them for summing. There may be no such elegant way -- I just figured it was a common use-case. Comes up in accounting all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is actually pretty optimized already. The only problem — you are fetching one download at a time. Use `u.downloads.all.group_by` (add `all` in there) in order to load all downloads at once. This way you're pretty much down to one query.

**Update:** Although on the second look, in Rails 3 this shouldn't even produce multiple queries. There are numerous reasons why you may experience N+1 issues. For example, if you back-reference a particular download from some associated object somewhere in your view - rails may not know that this download was already fetched from database as part of your array, and re-fetch it again. If you see many queries — this code shouldn't be causing them.

Comment: I believe there is a back-reference to an associated model, but I'll check out using eager loading to mitigate that. My concern was twofold: 1) Often letting the database do the heavy lifting is a smarter way to offload the processing -- I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something; and 2) At a certain number of rows, doing the in-memory group_by gets very expensive -- I'm concerned that page loads will start to get pokey if there is any significant amount of traffic. I recognize that there are apps that just *are* this way. It just seemed like a common use-case so it was worth an ask.

Comment: Thing is - no matter who creates credit sums (ruby or database), database has to spit out all of the downloads. Once you past that concern, in my opinion you should sleep well at night until something actually calls for attention. You did everything right up to this point, extra actions will be premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already performing the iteration yourself, you can also do the sum:

```
u.downloads.group_by(&:download_date).each do |date, downloads|
  subtotal_credits = 0
  downloads.each do |d|
    puts " %10s  %3d" % [d.download_date, subtotal_credits += d.credits]
  end
  puts "*%10s  %3d" % [date, subtotal_credits]
end
```